# Strange behavior in Grantha

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, indic

I am using the velthuis-sanskrit-grantha.map found at
https://www.mail-archive.com/xetex@tug.org/msg11336.html

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\grt}{
           \catcode`\^=12
            \catcode`\~=12
            \fontspec[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit-grantha,Scale=1]{Noto Sans Grantha}}

\begin{document}
{\grt maanaatiitaprathitavibhavaam ma"ngaLam ma"ngaLaanaam\\
vak.sa.hpii.thiim madhuvijayino bhuu.sayantiim svakaantyaa|\\
pratyak.saanu"sravikamahimapraarthiniinaam prajaanaam\\
"sreyomuurtim "sriyama"sara.nastvaam "sara.nyaam prapadye||\par}

\vspace{0.5cm}

{\grt maanaatiitaprathitavibhavaam ma"ngaLam ma"ngaLaanaam\\
vak.sa.hpii.thiim madhuvijayino bhuu.sayantiim svakaantyaa|\\
pratyak.saanu"sravikamahimapraarthiniinaam prajaanaam\\
"sreyomuurtim "sriyama"sara.nastvaam "sara.nyaam prapadye||\par}

\end{document}
```

The two sets of four-liners are exactly the same. The output is

[image]

The third line in the first set is wrong while the same line in the second set is correct.

---

**Edit**: Here's a smaller input file with an even starker difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\tracinglostchars=2
\newcommand{\grt}{
           \catcode`\^=12
            \catcode`\~=12
            \fontspec[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit-grantha]{Noto Sans Grantha}}

\begin{document}

Here is a test.

{\grt pratyak.saanu"sravikamahima}

{\grt pratyak.saanu"sravikamahima}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: second example]

You can download the `velthuis-sanskrit-grantha.map` file from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f8c639c3184c7000103a372) (and also download the font if it's not on your system); the `.tec` file is generated by the command `teckit_compile velthuis-sanskrit-grantha.map`

Comment: OK, after fixing some errors in the `.map` file (caused by line wrapping in the web UI above), I was able to get it to work, and the output I get matches what is in the question… very intriguing.

Comment: I get an even weirder diff with `{\grt pratyak.saanu"sravikamahima}` and `{\grt pratyak.saanu"sravikamahima}` — the first time the output is just one glyph! For anyone else wanting to reproduce this: try the `.map` and `.tec` files from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zsbhxqpqjspx). This is probably an issue with the mapping file…

Comment: I've edited the other example into the question (and linked to a working version of the `.map` and generated `.tec` files, and font) — hope it's ok; feel free to revert.

Comment: That is perfectly fine @ShreevatsaR If I use the same text with e-GranTamil font, which uses the Bengali codespace, the output is perfect.